# Which one of these transistors is equivalent to 2N918 NPN?

Tags: transistors, radio, datasheet, frequency-modulation, resonance

[image]

This is an FM radio receiver. Q1 is 2N918 NPN transistor but it is not available for me.

Which one of the following transistors is more equivalent to Q1 ?

BC547

TL431

s8550

s9014

2n5401

2n5551

I've read their datasheets but I'm not an expert, so I need your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of those transistors (nor the TL431 regulator) are particularly suitable.

Look for an NPN silicon transistor with an ft of 600-800MHz. The best fit is the high-voltage 2N5401 with an ft of 300MHz, but at 100MHz+ FM it won't be that great.

Comment: The 2N5401 is PNP.

Comment: @molleranas If he's building the circuit he can flip it.